# Metric-like spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ a set $\sigma$ to $X^2$ into $[0,\infty)$ a function such as:

1)$\sigma(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$

2)$\sigma(x,y)=\sigma(y,x)$

3)$\sigma(x,z)\leq \sigma(x,y)+\sigma(y,z)$.

We define $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y,|\sigma(x,y)-\sigma(x,x)|<\varepsilon\}$.

$\tau_\sigma$ has as base the family of open $\sigma-$balls.
Can you explain me this point please, I try to show that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap B(y,\delta)$ is a reunion of balls.
Thank you

Comment: See also: [Does a metric-like space generate a topology if open balls are defined as $B_\sigma(X,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X; |\sigma(x,y)-\sigma(x,x)|<\varepsilon\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557780).