# When does a symmetric function give a base for a topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let us consider a set $X$ together with function $m\colon X\times X\to\mathbb R$ such that

- $m(x,y)=m(y,x)$ for $x,y\in X$
- $m(x,x)=0$
- $m(x,y)\ge 0$

This is similar to definition of metric, but we omitted triangle inequality and we allow $m(x,y)=0$ even for $x\ne y$.

Let us define $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X; m(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$. If we are working with metric, then $\{B(x,\varepsilon); \varepsilon>0\}$ is a local base at $x$, and $\{B(x,\varepsilon); \varepsilon>0, x\in X\}$ is a base for the corresponding metric topology.

How does this change by omitting the triangle inequality? Probably asking for a complete characterization would be overly ambitious, but at least we can ask this:

**Question.** Are there some sufficient/necessary conditions for $\{B(x,\varepsilon); \varepsilon>0, x\in X\}$ to be a base for a topology on $X$?

Clearly, triangle inequality is one sufficient condition. But perhaps more interesting question is how far we can get from metric spaces.

It is immediately obvious that triangle inequality is not necessary. If $m(x,y)\ge1$ for $x\ne y$, then we get a discrete topology. And we can change values of $m(x,y)$ in whatever way we like - in particular, we can easily break triangle inequality.

To give another very simple example, if we put $m(x,y)=0$ for each $x$, $y$, we get indiscrete space.

And to add at least one example when this is not a topology, consider $X=[0,1]$ with $m(0,1)=m(1,0)=1$ and $m(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Here the collection of all "balls" is $\{[0,1],[0,1),(1,0]\}$ and this is clearly not a basis.

---

My motivation for asking this is that rather similar functions appeared in a construction of a counterexample in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557780/does-a-metric-like-space-generate-a-topology-if-open-balls-are-defined-as-b-si/2557894#2557894). (For the problem where this originated, perhaps necessary conditions would be more interesting - since they can lead to constructions of some further counterexamples. My gut feeling is that necessary conditions are probably more difficult to find. I have decide to ask about both necessary or sufficient conditions - I think both of them can be interesting. Clearly, splitting the question into two parts - one asking about sufficient conditions and one asking about necessary conditions - would lead to two very similar questions about rather niche topic, which is definitely not optimal.)

---

The Wikipedia article on metric also defines the notion of [premetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Premetrics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metric_(mathematics)&oldid=814963588#Premetrics)) where only conditions $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)\ge0$ are required. (This is even more general - we do not require symmetry.)

According to the Wikipedia article, every premetric gives a topology but in this way: A set $U$ is open if for every $x\in U$ there exist some ball $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X; d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$ with $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. It is explicitly mentioned that these balls are not necessarily open. So this is *different way* of getting a topology from such functions from the way discussed in this question. (I have to admit that I did not check whether the claims given in the Wikipedia article are true and I did not even check the references given there. I have included this mainly for comparison with some similar notions which are already known - or at least notable enough to be mentioned in the Wikipedia article.)

Comment: Your definition of base gives structureless spaces that cannot even be shown  to be T0.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, I am aware of that. (To make this clearer I have added example with indiscrete space.) In fact, if we only consider these conditions we are not even guaranteed that the result is a topological space - the question asks about additional conditions which we can put on $d$ in order to get topological space.

Comment: Your ideas are close to the notion of a symmetrizable space (and semimetrics), that are studied in topology. See  e.g. [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-219-00/S0002-9947-1976-0418048-0/S0002-9947-1976-0418048-0.pdf); there are many more.

Comment: If you combine topology with vector spaces, the picture is clearer. The triangle inequality is equivalent to the convexity of the balls. But there are topological vector spaces that are not locally convex. For example, the metrics $m(x,y)=|x-y|^a$ where $a<1$ give so-called locally bounded spaces. In any case, the balls can still act as a sub-base to generate a base and topology.