# The inequality $\left\lceil\frac{a_1+\dots+a_k}k\right\rceil\le\left\lceil\frac{a_1}k\right\rceil+\dots+\left\lceil\frac{a_k}k\right\rceil$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In connection with [a problem I've asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582033/if-a-function-dx-y-fulfills-triangle-inequality-is-the-same-true-for-dx/2582172#2582172) I have noticed the inequality $$\left\lceil\frac{a+b}2\right\rceil \le \left\lceil\frac{a}2\right\rceil + \left\lceil\frac{b}2\right\rceil$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Unless I am missing something, we could prove in a similar way
$$\left\lceil\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k}k\right\rceil \le \left\lceil\frac{a_1}k\right\rceil + \left\lceil\frac{a_2}k\right\rceil + \dots + \left\lceil\frac{a_k}k\right\rceil.$$
Again, only for *integer* values of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$. EDIT: As the answerers pointed out, this is in fact true for *real* numbers, not only for integers.

Is there a simple proof for this inequality? (Ideally without considering too many separated cases.)

Can this inequality be strengthened in some way?

Comment: The statement is also true for real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_k$, as my proof below shows.

Comment: @P.Koymans Yes, I've noticed this after your answer. I remember that I thought I had a counterexample when thinking about the $k=2$ version, but since I tried various versions back then (some of them with floor function) I have probably mixed up something. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that by definition $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that $n \geq x$. Now in order to show that
$$
\lceil \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k}{k} \rceil \leq \lceil \frac{a_1}{k} \rceil + \lceil \frac{a_2}{k} \rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{a_k}{k} \rceil,
$$
we merely have to show that
$$
\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k}{k} \leq \lceil \frac{a_1}{k} \rceil + \lceil \frac{a_2}{k} \rceil + \cdots + \lceil \frac{a_k}{k} \rceil,
$$
since the RHS is an integer. But this is straightforward.

Comment: This is much better indeed. Good job Peter :)

Answer (score 2):

Fix $k>0$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in \mathbf{R}$. Then, there exist unique $b_1,\ldots,b_k \in \mathbf{Z}$ and $c_1,\ldots,c_k \in [0,k)$ such that $a_i=kb_i+c_i$. Hence the inequality reduces to
$$
\left\lceil \sum_{i\le k}\frac{c_i}{k}\right\rceil \le \sum_{i\le k}\left\lceil \frac{c_i}{k} \right\rceil
$$
Let $x$ be the number of $i\le k$ such that $c_i\neq 0$. Then the inequality can be rewritten as 
$$
\left\lceil \sum_{i\le k, \,c_i \neq 0}\frac{c_i}{k}\right\rceil \le x.
$$
This is true because
$$
\left\lceil \sum_{i\le k, \,c_i \neq 0}\frac{c_i}{k}\right\rceil \le \left\lceil \frac{x\cdot k}{k}\right\rceil \le x.
$$